# Receive-Job: Not Getting Results

Tags: powershell

I am trying to return a list of group members from a job but get no results from `Receive-Job`.  I want to get the variable containing the array or pass to a new array.

Example code below.  How would I get the `Receive-Job` to return the data in `$objGroupMembers`?

```psh
Start-Job -Name 'GroupName' -ScriptBlock {
    Get-PSSnapin -Registered | Add-PSSnapin;

    $aryProperties = @(
        "SamAccountName"
        "employeeid"
        "firstname"
        "lastname"
        "email"
        "title"
        "department"
    )

    $objGroupMembers = Get-QADGroupMember -Identity "GroupName" -Indirect -SizeLimit 0 -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -IncludedProperties $aryProperties | Select-Object $aryProperties 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your job isn't returning anything. Basically a job is like running a new console in the background. Any output made to that console can be retrieved with Receive-Job. However in your case, you assigned the result to your variable and that's it. The following should help:

```
Start-Job -Name 'GroupName' -ScriptBlock {
    Get-PSSnapin -Registered | Add-PSSnapin;

    $aryProperties = @(
    "SamAccountName"
    "employeeid"
    "firstname"
    "lastname"
    "email"
    "title"
    "department"
    )


    $objGroupMembers = Get-QADGroupMember -Identity "GroupName" -Indirect -SizeLimit 0 -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -IncludedProperties $aryProperties | Select-Object $aryProperties 

    $objGroupMembers
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can't believe I didn't catch that.  Works great, now to improve all my team's Po$h scripts.

Comment: Instead of echoing `$objGroupMembers` just don't assign the output of `Get-QADGroupMember` to a variable in the first place.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Yup, I wrote it like that for the sake of the explanation, however I agree with you.